# Access Google Groups API after revoking permission to user

Tags: google-api, google-groups-api, google-admin-sdk

I've noticed a strange behaviour with Google Groups API (Admin SDK v1), while trying to create/retrieve a group:

1. Initially, I use an user X to create/retrieve Google Groups with Admin SDK; user X does have permissions to operate on groups and all works fine;
2. In administration console, I removed from user X the permissions to operate on groups; now all operations performed from Admin SDK using user X fails (with a 403 Forbidden - Not Authorized to access this resource/api), and it's right;
3. After re-enabling from administration console the permissions for user X, I'm still getting the same error (403) with Admin SDK, even after a week from re-enabling permissions; if I use user X from google panel, I'm able to create groups, only from Admin SDK I'm getting the 403.

Does anyone got the same problem or know the reason?

Comment: Have you check if this issue occur using other users as well?

Comment: Of course, I tried with multiple users